# How to use 5 variables all of which change after each row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do you change automatically change the J,K,L,M,R Value's from row 1 to the last row in VBA? I also need it to post the outcome in a cell after each loop from row 1 to the last row.

Quite a hard question so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub NewCode()



    Dim lastRow As Variant
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, "J").Value = "EGM1" And _
            Cells(i, "K").Value = "1100" And _
            Cells(i, "L").Value <= "2.0253" And _
            Cells(i, "M").Value >= "2.0253" And _
            Cells(i, "R").Value = "S&C" Then

            counter = counter + 1

        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "Number of Defects: " & counter


End Sub
```

Edit 1: So, i have sheet 1 on excel that has information like ELR (J), TrackID(K), Start milage(L), End milage(M), Rail type(R). and i have an other excel sheet with the same titles but with different information. i need to use the information in sheet 1 (starting at row 2) and see if any rows in sheet 2 match that specific row in sheet 1. Then print in a cell in sheet 1 how many matches there were, and repeat going down the info in sheet 1.. But i cant seem to pull the initial information from sheet 1 and then print it. Hope that helps

Edit 2: I tried using `COUNTIFS()` but when i try and test it by saying look for a number larger than 1 (which is has hundreds of), i keep just getting 0.

```
 =COUNTIFS('Defects (OPEN)'!L:L, ">1" )
```

Comment: Not so much a hard question as an unclear one... Can you please post sample data and expected output?

Comment: Why not use `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: So, i have sheet 1 on excel that has information like ELR (J), TrackID(K), Start milage(L), End milage(M), Rail type(R). and i have an other excel sheet with the same titles but with different information. i need to use the information in sheet 1 (starting at row 2) and see if any rows in sheet 2 match that specific row in sheet 1. Then print in a cell in sheet 1 how many matches there were, and repeat going down the info in sheet 1.. But i cant seem to pull the initial information from sheet 1 and then print it. Hope that helps

Comment: Please do not add clarity through the comments, but [edit] your question to include that clarifications.

Comment: And it really sounds like [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842) is what you're looking for

Comment: I've tried useing macro, but i keep getting a 0 value, is there a way to do it useing a macro so i can clarify my results?

Comment: Your syntax looks fine, is `Defects (OPEN)` really the name of the sheet? (look for spaces at the beginning or end of the sheet name)

Comment: Also looks like you only need one variable for this, or even none, depending on implementation

Comment: are your numbers stored as text?

Comment: use `texttocolumns` to ensure your strings are displaying numbers; if that alone does not resolve the issue with your countif (which looks correct syntactically), i would recommend using a named range for the columns so you don't have to call sheets, etc., in your `countifs()`